# VisualStudio Ctrl + F5 doesn't start the server after installing VSCommands

Tags: visual-studio-2013, iis-express

I have installed VS Commands for VS2013, but then the functionality of Ctrl F5 - run without debugging - stopped working. I builds the app, opens browser window, but doesn't load anything, instead I get Error: ConnectionRefused.

But when I hit just the F5, it does work just fine. It all worked before I installed the VS Commands, does anyone have any idea how to get it back to the previous working state? I didn't install or use any firewall or anti virus software. I tried it in Chrome and Firefox both with the same result.

Now I have opened a different projects (before it didn't work on any projects I opened) and it does work there, but just this one.

I hope I'm not creating a duplicate but couldn't find anything related to this problem.
Thanks

Comment: Go into your settings for the keyboard and re-map it to run without debugging.

Comment: Well, the shortcut does work, it opens the browser window, but it doesn't load anything - connection refused. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 1):

So the solution was to change settings under Options/Projects and Solutions/Web Projects and here Use 64bit version of IIS Express.. Not sure if that was due to the VSCommands, might be just unfortunate coincidence.

[image: Options screenshot]